# how to get pk value of another model in current model's get absolute url django

Tags: django

I am learning django. I am very new to programming. I have one model as below:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    group_description = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        self.save()
        return reverse('group-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

now I am creating another model which needs the pk value of the above Group model:
class GroupPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('group-post-detail', kwargs={'pk': Group.pk, 'pk2': self.pk})
```

when I give just Group.pk it is erroring out giving the below information.

Reverse for 'group-post-detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': , 'pk2': 73}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['groups/(?P[0-9]+)/post/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

How can I get rid of the error message. what is the correct way to proceed? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should have a many-to-one relationship (`ForeignKey`) with the `Group` model from the `GroupPost` model, as each post belongs to a certain group and one group can have many posts.

So add a `ForeignKey`:

```
class GroupPost(models.Model):
    ...
    group = models.ForeignKey('Group', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now, you can refer the related `Group` `id` (or `pk`) from a `GroupPost` instance:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('group-post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.group.pk, 'pk2': self.pk})
    #                                                 ^^^^^^ Here
```

Assuming the view name is `group-post-detail`.

Also, rather than referring URL keywords as `pk` and `pk2`, you can be more explicit:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('group-post-detail', kwargs={'group_pk': self.group.pk, 'group_post_pk': self.pk})
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I tried implementing your suggestion. when I did migrations I got non nullable field error. So I added null=True while calling the Group model. So when I refresh my url I am getting below error:                                              
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value: 
No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model.

Comment: @desi123 Don't make the field nullable. That's the whole point of the new design. As you're just starting out, see if you can recreate the database. If not, we need to modify stuffs.

Comment: hey can you tell me what this error means:  
NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_grouppost.group_id. do I need to give a default value